# Как нарисовать фигуру подобную картинке

Tags: android, android-drawable

Как нарисовать подобную фигуру в xml. И стоит ли ее рисовать, или лучше использовать png (будет использоваться в качестве кнопки  и будет в дальнейшем анимироваться)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте **9-patch png**.
Добавьте к изображению раму толщиной в один пиксель, которая будет содержать информацию для растягивания изображения и размещения на нем контента. [image: вот пример]

И измените расширение файла на имя_файла.9.png

В дальнейшем это изображение можно будет использовать в качестве фона, который будет растягиваться в нужных местах, таким же образом делаются разные облачка для диалогов и.т.д.

Преобразовать также можно с помощью png to 9-patch сервисов.